# Multi-Var Calc: Surface Integrals

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

A thin sheet has the shape of the surface S. If its density (mass per unit area)

at the point $(x, y, z)$ is $ρ(x, y, z)$, then its center of mass is

$(x, y, z)$,
 where
$x = 1/m$ (double integral) $(xρ(x, y, z) dS)$

$y = 1/m$ (double integral) $(yρ(x, y, z) dS)$

$z = 1/m$ (double integral) $(zρ(x, y, z) dS)$

and $m$ is the mass of the sheet. Find the center of mass of the sheet.

S is the part of the paraboloid  $z = 12 − (1/6)x^2 − (1/6)y^2, 
z ≥ 0, ρ(x, y, z) = k$,  where $k$ is a constant.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: The surface is a surface of revolution of uniform density, the center of mass will lie on the axis of revolution.

Answer (score 0):

$x = r\cos t\\
y =r \sin t\\
z = 12 - \frac 16 r^2$

$dS = \|(\frac {\partial x}{\partial r},\frac {\partial y}{\partial r},\frac {\partial z}{\partial r}) \times(\frac {\partial x}{\partial t},\frac {\partial y}{\partial t},\frac {\partial z}{\partial t}) \| = r\sqrt{\frac {r^2}{9} +1}\ dr\ dt$

$m = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\sqrt{72} \rho(r,t) r \sqrt {\frac {r^2}{9} + 1} \ dr \ dt\\
2\pi k \int_0^\sqrt{72} r \sqrt {\frac {r^2}{9} + 1} \ dr\\
u = \frac {r^2}{9} + 1\\
du = \frac 29 r\\
(2\pi k) \int_1^9 \frac {9}{2}\sqrt u \ du\\
(2\pi k) 3u^{\frac {3}{2}}|_1^9\\
(2\pi k) 3(26)$

$\bar z = \frac {2\pi k}{m} \int_0^\sqrt{72} r (12-\frac 16 r^2) \sqrt {\frac {r^2}{9} + 1}\ dr$

Do the indentical u-sub as above.

$\bar z = \frac {1}{78}\int_1^9  \frac {27}{4}(9-u)\sqrt u \ du$

$\bar x = $$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\sqrt{72} r^2\cos t \sqrt {\frac {r^2}{9} + 1} \ dr \ dt\\
\int_0^{2\pi} \cos t\ dt \int_0^\sqrt{72} r^2\sqrt {\frac {r^2}{9} + 1} \ dr = 0$

$\bar y = 0$

Comment: So the X and Y coordinates are zero and Z is just solving that integral?

Comment: Who cares about the last step.  What is important is how to get there.  Do understand what I have done?  I have not spelled out all of the steps.  Can you see through the short-cuts?

Comment: Yes, I understand this now, thanks!